# Confidence prediction in Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Confidence level to sequence prediction in Stanford NER Tagger. It's possible? Confidence for a given predicted sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that can print out the k (in the example 10) most likely sequences, and will print out the sequence probability.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.DocumentReaderAndWriter;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Triple;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;


public class GetCRFProbsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        String serializedClassifier = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
        AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(serializedClassifier);
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("Ten best entity labelings");
        DocumentReaderAndWriter<CoreLabel> readerAndWriter = classifier.makePlainTextReaderAndWriter();
        classifier.classifyAndWriteAnswersKBest(args[0], 10, readerAndWriter);
    }

}
```